# Not getting any requests for Facebook Real Time page updates

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

First things first, I apologize, since I know there are other questions related to this on StackOverflow already. Unfortunately, none of them seemed to have comprehensive answers, and others did not solve the issue I am having.

I am attempting to register for real time updates on Facebook for a **page**. Essentially, when an admin of a page posts a status update, or shares something, I'd like to be notified about it.

### GRAPH API Version

Before I begin, I'd like to start out by saying that I'm using **Facebook's GRAPH API v2.3**. I have noticed some messages on the [/app-id/subscriptions GRAPH API edge documentation page](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.3/app/subscriptions/) stating that "some features were removed in v2.2".

I have not tested with v2.2 of the API, however I can if anyone thinks it might be relevant. I can't imagine Facebook would just remove that feature, but at this point I'm not ruling anything out. :)

### What I've Tried So Far...

I set up my app to have a **Tab Page** component, and succesfully filled out all required information for this in the App Control Panel. This was required for my next step, which was adding the application as a tab to my page.

To my understanding, it is required that my app be a tab on the page I am wanting updates for in order to receive updates for that page. (Or at least, the page needs to have "installed" the app, which occurs when the app is added as a tab)

---

I've made a `POST` request to `/page-id/tabs` to create a tab for my app on my page. Now, when I make a `GET` request to `/page-id/tabs` I can see my app contained in the list of tabs for my page:

```
{
  "id": "app_id/tabs/tab_id", 
  "image_url": "...", 
  "name": "My Tab Name", 
  "link": "...", 
  "application": {
    "name": "My App", 
    "id": "app_id"
  }, 
  "is_permanent": false, 
  "position": 5, 
  "is_non_connection_landing_tab": false
}
```

---

I've made a `POST` request to `/app-id/subscriptions` to create both a `user` and `page` subscription for my app. Both subscriptions subscribe to the `field` parameter. When I make a request to `/app-id/subscriptions` I get the following response:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "object": "user", 
      "callback_url": "my_callback_url", 
      "fields": [
        "feed"
      ], 
      "active": true
    }, 
    {
      "object": "page", 
      "callback_url": "my_callback_url", 
      "fields": [
        "feed"
      ], 
      "active": true
    }
  ]
}
```

And just to confirm, when I created the subscription, I *did* receive a request to my callback URL for verification, and--as far as I can tell--successfully passed validation because I was given a successful response when I created the subscriptions.

---

Finally, I have made a `GET` request to `/page-id/subscribed_apps`. I'm concerned since I am *not* seeing my app in this response:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "name": "Discussion Boards", 
      "id": "2373072738"
    }
  ]
}
```

### The Problem

So, after all of this, when I make a post as my page, I do **not** receive any `POST` request from Facebook to my callback URL.

It may be important to note that a colleague of mine has been able to receive `user` updates from his personal profile using pretty much the same steps. I can't currently receive `user` updates with my profile, but I assume that's because I haven't authenticated my app with my Facebook profile.

### Questions / Thoughts / Theories

- Am I missing some obvious (or not-so-obvious) step that needs to be performed in order for Facebook to send me notification requests?
- Does my app need to go through Facebook's [Login Review](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review/login) or something similar in order to receive page updates?
- Is this just broken? If so, any workarounds?

Comment: Creating a subscription for pages is not done via `/page_id/tabs` any more, but via `/page_id/subscribed_apps`, see https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog#v2_2_new_features

Comment: Oh? Interesting! I'll give that a try. I had previously consulted the `/page_id/subscribed_apps` documentation [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.3/page/subscribed_apps) and it still states you can't create anything with that API edge, but the change log you linked me to seems to suggest otherwise. Thanks!

Comment: Alright, that worked! Feel free to post this as the answer and I am happy to accept it. Thank you so much!

Comment: This may give idea of a complete flow of page subscription: http://tech-brains.blogspot.in/2015/04/real-time-updates-for-facebook-page.html

Comment: @JesseDunlap did you manage to get posts with picture to your webhook? I'm struggling with similar subscription (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39135845/subscribe-to-facebook-page-photos-using-pages-api-webhook). So far I'm getting new posts from facebook, but not those with photos

Comment: @Troggy if I remember correctly, we didn't get the photo included in the update. You have to make an API request separately to obtain that using whatever unique identifier Facebook sends to you. As for actually receiving or not receiving updates when they have attached photos, like in your question, I'm not sure. Seems like there could be some bugs in Facebook's API. Sorry I couldn't be more helpful, good luck!

Comment: thanks @JesseDunlap. Yep, I've found this is well-known facebook issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Creating a subscription for pages is not done via `/page_id/tabs` any more, but via a POST request `/page_id/subscribed_apps`. No additional parameters necessary (besides a page access token, obviously), it automatically generates a subscription for the app used to make the request.

This is currently mentioned in the changelog, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog#v2_2_new_features

It should be mentioned under https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.3/page/subscribed_apps as well – but it looks like Facebook are in the process of restructuring their documentation (once again), and have not fully caught up with current state of their API yet.