# Subscribe to Facebook Page photos using Pages API webhook

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, permissions, webhooks

**TL/DR;**

With page webhook in place, if I upload new photo to the Page via Photos Facebook notifies my webhook. If I do the same on page timeline — it doesn't.

**Details:**

I want my application to receive new posts from some public Facebook page. Posts may have a photo attached or may not.

**What have I done:**

In my Facebook app settings I've created a Page Subscription in Webhooks section. I've chosen 'feed' field.
I've subscribed my app to the target page using "/subscribed_apps" endpoint. Page access token with "manage_pages" permission was used for that.

**Problem:**

Facebook is calling my webhook and my app receives text posts from the page, so basically subscription works. But if I attach an image to the post, Facebook doesn't trigger the webhook. I don't see any other sensible field to choose for Page Subscription and I've tried almost all of the other fields as well with no luck.

I'm stuck. It looks like I need to fine-tune some permission somewhere, but just don't see which else to try. Is it ever possible to subscribe for new page photos?

**UPD:**

If I upoad new photo via Photos Facebook notifies my webhook. If I do the same via page timeline — it doesn't. Looks like a bug

**UPD2:**

Fixed by Facebook team. Now works as expected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, this is confirmed bug in Facebook Realtime API: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/1740620369486641/

**UPD:**
Fixed by the Facebook team. Now subscription works as expected